# WP Contact Form 7 Styling issue select

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm stuck on a styling issue with WP's contact form 7 plugin again.

This screenshot shows how it looks - apparently, it's set to "width: 100" but the button is centred - so, it's not at 100%.

[image: Contact form on my website]

The code I used for my contact form is this:

```css
/* my custom css*/

input[type=submit] {
   background: none;
   color: #1fbba6;
   border: 2px solid #1fbba6;
   border-radius: 50px !important;
   padding: 14px 14px;
   font-weight: 400;
   font-size: 12px;
  width: 140px !important;
    }

.wpcf7 {
     width: 100%;
}

input[type=select] {
width: 100% !important;
 color: #d9d9d9;
}

input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-submit:hover {
   background: none;
   color: #1fbba6;
}

.wpcf7-form select {
width: 100% !important;
}

/* classes that are provided from my theme*/

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0)
template.min.css?ver=4.15.13:1
.kl-fancy-form-select {
    height: 52px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.06);
    background-image: url(../images/select-arrow.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 6px 12px;
    background-position: calc(100% - 10px) 50%;
    background-position-y: center;
    background-position-x: calc(100% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<label>[text* your-name placeholder "Dein Name*"] </label>

<label>[email* your-email placeholder "Deine E-Mail*"] </label>

<label>[tel phone placeholder "Telefon"]</label>

<label>[select* class:zn_form_input class:form-control--light class:kl-fancy-form-select training "Ich interessiere mich für:" "Personal Training" "Mini-Kurse" "Rückbildung" "Sonstiges"]</label>

<label>[textarea your-message placeholder "Deine Nachricht"] </label>

<center>[submit "Nachricht senden"]</center>
```

Why is it not accepting my "width: 100%!important;"? What can I do to make it accept that?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: it's not enough .. add this `.wpcf7-form-control-wrap, label {width:100%}` the container should first be 100%

Comment: What? It was that simple, really? Thank you for your help! It worked.